# Laravel - to access appends property in a joined query of eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have searched all over the place, I just couldn't seem to get the correct answer.

Consider the following classes

```
class A extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['encoded_name'];

    public function getEncodedNameAttribute()
    {
        return "ABC_ENCODED_NAME";
    }
}

class B extends Model
{

}
```

Now, these 2 classes are related through a column.

I have a controller that joins these 2 tables together, but class B acts as my base table, like so:

```
$query = B::query();
$query = $query->join('a', 'a.id', '=', 'b.a_id');
$query = $query->select('a.*');
```

With the query above, I can access the properties in my blade.php pages in a loop  by simply calling

> $a->example_property;

However, when I try to access the `appends` property, using

> $a->encoded_name;

It doesn't seem to work that way. Am I missing out on something?

Comment: How are you running your query that gets the data from the tables? Are you using the actual model, or are you using DB?  If you are using DB to make the query, you won't get any methods or properties specific to your Class A or Class B models.

Comment: I'm using the actual model's `query()` method. Not from using DB

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize that was the full query.  I think you are creating an object using class B.  If you put the `getEncodedNameAttribute()` function in class B, does it work as expected?  Your syntax all seems correct.  If you create a new object of class A, does it show the encoded_name property?

Answer (score 0):

Because $appends only work with Eloquent, when you do a join, your queries stop being an eloquent query instead it's now a query builder. That's why.

Create Proper has one or has many relationships and try to access your append attribute accordingly. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to detail example about how to get User Model's Accessor in another model with using relationship

Suppose, we have User table & Comment Table...

Now, Suppose I appends User's Profile Full URL in User model using **"getProfilePhotoUrlAttribute"** Method. when I call User model eloquent then it's appends User Profile Image automatically.

but Now I wants to get that user's profile Full URL in with Comments then we can't access Accessor using Join because with join we can join only out DataBase's Table Columns. If we have profile_photo_path column & doesn't have profile_photo_url named column as we define accessor function name then we can't access using jjoin. in this case we wants to use Relationship method

For example:-

> **Case :- 1 You wants to Get the user's comments with User details**

In this case, User have one or more than one comments So we need to use **One TO Many Relation**

> App/Models/User.php file

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = [
    'profile_photo_url',
];

/**
 * Get the URL to the user's profile photo.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProfilePhotoUrlAttribute()
{
    ... here return full profile URL (concat profile_path with storage/public location path)... 
}

/**
 * Get the user's comments with User details.
 * 
 * One To Many relation
 */
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Now then, use Model eloquent Query like below

```
$user = User::with('comments')->where('id', '=', '2')->get();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user->toarray());
```

**see Output of One To Many Relation**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => test
            [email] => test@test.com
            [email_verified_at] => 2021-02-04T07:21:36.000000Z
            [contact] => 1234567890
            [current_team_id] => 
            [profile_photo_path] => users/user16148609746040d2ae9dd81.png
            [role_id] => 3
            [created_at] => 2020-12-11T02:03:17.000000Z
            [updated_at] => 2021-09-02T06:49:56.000000Z
            [profile_photo_url] => http://localhost:8000/storage/users/user16148609746040d2ae9dd81.png
            [comments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [deal_id] => 45
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [comment] => test
                            [status] => 0
                            [parent_comment_id] => 
                            [comment_like] => 0
                            [created_at] => 
                            [updated_at] => 2021-09-02T12:41:34.000000Z
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

> **Case :- 2 You wants to Get the user details of the all comments.**
> In this case, we need to use Many TO One Relation
>
> App/Models/Comment.php file

```
 /**
 * Get the user details of the comments.
 * 
 * One To Many (Inverse) / Belongs To
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

then use Model eloquent Query like below

```
$comments = Comment::where('deal_id', '=', '45')->get();

print_r($comments->toarray());

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    print_r($comment->user->toarray());
    echo $comment->user->profile_photo_url;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

**see Output of $comments**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [deal_id] => 45
            [user_id] => 3
            [comment] => Superb Deal
            [status] => 1
            [parent_comment_id] => 
            [comment_like] => 1
            [created_at] => 2021-04-02T08:41:22.000000Z
            [updated_at] => 2021-04-02T08:41:22.000000Z
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [deal_id] => 45
            [user_id] => 3
            [comment] => I purchased this phone with this deal
            [status] => 1
            [parent_comment_id] => 1
            [comment_like] => 0
            [created_at] => 2021-04-02T08:41:51.000000Z
            [updated_at] => 2021-04-02T08:41:51.000000Z
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [deal_id] => 45
            [user_id] => 2
            [comment] => test
            [status] => 0
            [parent_comment_id] => 
            [comment_like] => 0
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2021-09-02T12:41:34.000000Z
        )

)
```

**see Output of $comment->user**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => test
    [email] => test@gmail.com
    [email_verified_at] => 2021-02-04T07:21:36.000000Z
    [contact] => 1234567890
    [current_team_id] => 
    [profile_photo_path] => users/user16148609746040d2ae9dd81.png
    [role_id] => 4
    [created_at] => 2020-12-11T04:51:29.000000Z
    [updated_at] => 2021-03-27T09:52:28.000000Z
    [profile_photo_url] => http://localhost:8000/storage/users/user16148609746040d2ae9dd81.png
)
```

& **see Output of $comment->user->profile_photo_url**

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/users/user16148609746040d2ae9de21.png
http://localhost:8000/storage/users/user16148609746040d2ae9dd81.png
```

> **NOTE:- I used Latest version - it is Laravel 8, So Syntax may vary as per your Laravel Version**